# application insights configuration in yml

Tags: azure-application-insights

We are using [DropWizard](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs/getting-started.html) to create java applications running as a server inside a docker container.

Command to create such applications is as below -

```
java -jar service-name.jar server service-name.yml
```

service-name.yml is a file that holds all configuration settings.

Can you suggest how do we configure application insights inside this yml file?

Comment: Your question is too broad. You should specify details related with your questions in order to get help from the community. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask In this page you can read more on how to ask good questions

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how DropWizard configuration reading works. But if there are hooks in the code to read the configuration, you can read all the configuration required for ApplicationInsights and manually configure in your code using [TelemetryInitializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.applicationinsights.extensibility.telemetryconfiguration.aspx).